# MySQL: So many prepared statements in general log file

Tags: mysql, performance, log, prepared-statement

One of my clients complained serious performance issues in a web-application written in Java. I was suspecting that there might be some unoptimized queries which are causing the problem. I've enabled mysql general logging to figure out what queries are running behind a problematic application function. There were around **11840** '*Prepare*' statements in the log whereas '*Execute*' statements were only **9** in number - I couldn't understand what does this mean, can somebody assist? Thanks

Comment: For performance issues, enable the slowlog with `long_query_time=1`.  Later use `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest` to find the 'worst' queries.

Comment: Perhaps his code prepares thousands of possible queries, then picks the one he needs to execute.  (Inefficient way to do things.)

Comment: Thank you for the help. In fact I already checked this parameter. But the problem is not of _long running queries_ but is of _a lot of queries_ with `prepare` prefix against a single application function.
So I am not able to understand the reason of too many `prepare` statements without the `execute` statements.

Comment: How rapidly were the prepares executed -- that is perpares/minute or per second?  If hundreds were done in a few seconds, that might support the code pattern I was guessing about.

Comment: **11840** prepares in a minute or so, and only **9** were executed

Comment: Find the code...